# Steam destroys my Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, steam

I had to install Ubuntu 4 times to realise what was happening.

The problem is basically that following this few steps Ubuntu gets frozen on loading screen (before login).

1. Install Ubuntu 12.04.2
2. Update software
3. Install Steam from steampowered.com

After this I can perfectly download and play any available game, but the next time I reboot my system it will not load =(

Anyone with the same problem or some suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Hello loxiw and welcome on Ask Ubuntu ! Try doing steps 1 and 2, then reboot. See if the not-loading is already occurring without Steam or not. Furthermore, could you be a little more precise about that "not loading" ?

Comment: If it's a bug in Steam contact Valve and tell them as bugs are off-topic here.

Comment: I can confirm that it loads before the first two steps, and it gets frozen between selecting Ubuntu in grub and the login (account selection), in the screen with Ubuntu's logo.

Comment: @UriHerrera Reporting a bug upstream in Steam is not going to fix a broken Ubuntu system. A bug may have *caused* the problem here, but  the problem is now separate from the bug, and we're probably the best people to fix it. **loxiw**: You should report this as a bug, though, unless you have reason to believe it has some other cause (for example, if you installed other software or made configuration changes unrelated to Steam). When you see the splash screen (with the Ubuntu logo, where it's freezing), press Escape. This should reveal the text "behind" the splash. What does it say?

Answer (score 2):

It seems steam's repo has not been updated to support 12.04.2 yet. as you can see in this screenshot steam tries to downgrade a crapload of important packages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP0IS.png

Comment: That's the package from the Software Center or from steam's website?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is [downgraded packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/256690/22949), then it can probably be solved like this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Now you can log in non-graphically. As you enter your password, you won't see anything happening on the screen--that's normal.
2. Run `sudo apt-get remove steam` and `sudo apt-get remove steam64`. (I've listed them as separate commands in case for any reason APT doesn't know about either package--the other will still be uninstalled.)
3. Update packages back to their previous state by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get -y upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
4. Reboot the machine: `sudo reboot`

Your system will likely be fixed. If it is not, or if you are unable to complete these steps (for example, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't do anything), please update your question with more information (and also with [the information I requested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256673/steam-destroys-my-ubuntu#comment320121_256673)).

Comment: Nop, still doesn't load, thank you anyway :)

Comment: @loxiw Were you able to perform all those steps, and it didn't work? Or were you not able to run them? Were there any error messages?

Comment: By the way by clicking Esc in that screen it takes me to the login (by console) and all seems fine... I'm a really noob in Linux so I don't know if something is wrong there.

Comment: I did all the steps without errors, but still doesn't load...

Comment: Pressing F2 is even worse, the screen frozens before even loading Ubuntu's logo XD. This is the screen http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/145/84826257.jpg/

Comment: *Once* you get to that screen, what happens when you press Escape?

Comment: When it shows the logo it gets completely frozen and nothing happens pressing Esc/F2/random (except ctrl+alt+supr), and if I press Esc before that it takes me to the login with command line mode.

Comment: In that case, we should look at the package manager's logs, to see if there was some other change made when Steam was installed, that may be breaking things. Please run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pastebinit` followed by these commands: (1) `pastebinit -b http://paste.ubuntu.com /var/log/dpkg.log` (2) `pastebinit -b http://paste.ubuntu.com /var/log/apt/history.log` (3) `pastebinit -b http://paste.ubuntu.com /var/log/apt/term.log`   Those `pastebinit` commands will output URL's. Please edit your question to provide all three (identifying which log file each corresponds to).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a solution. I had what seems to be the same problem--on a fully updated clean installation of Ubuntu 12.04.2 64-bit with the AMD 13.1 driver, I installed Steam and rebooted, and the system did not load.

At the Steam Community website, I found [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864959809808921128/) by [JohnV](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198075101495):

> #### "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" workaround
>
> I was able to reproduce one of the "Package dependencies cannot be
> resolved" issues today. It happens if you install the Ubuntu 12.04.2
> x64 build and then search and install Steam from the Ubuntu Software
> Center. We are looking into this now.
>
> ...
>
> Sorry we did not catch this earlier, but I think the 12.04.2 just came
> out yesterday so we did not test it.

[d2kx](http://steamcommunity.com/id/dennis_martin_herbers) posted [an answer](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864959809808921128/#c864959809863728820):

> @Valve: If you simply update Ubuntu 12.04/12.04.1, there are no
> chances and Steam will work fine. The new Ubuntu 12.04.2 includes a
> backported graphics/kernel stack from Ubuntu 12.10 so it works on
> newer hardware. It uses packages that end with -lts-quantal (e.g.
> xserver-xorg-core-lts-quantal). You need to adapt the dependencies of
> the Steam .deb to reflect those changes and push the new version on
> the website *and* the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Understood, I suppose its a matter of time then :)